# I would like to create a very simple pivot table using vba, but I keep getting errors with my pivot cache

Tags: excel, vba

I have put together some VBA for a pivot table to basically just give how many CNs there are per person from the original table.  Maybe there is a more simple way to do this, but I have to have code as I plan on adding this code to a macro.  I have added a photo of my original table as well as what I am trying to have my pivot table look similar to.  I get an error message on the [ With ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Type")] line: Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class.  Any ideas?

[Example Table/pivot table photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2Hvq.png)  Thanks!

---

Sub PivotTableTest2()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable

Sheets("Supplier Quality").Activate

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=ws.Range("Table2"))

Set pt = ws.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pc, tabledestination:=ws.Range("P1"), TableName:="PivotTable1")
```

'

```
With ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Type")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Task Owner2")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Type"), "Sum of Tasks Overdue", xlSum
```

End Sub

Comment: What line errors and what is the error message?

Comment: a `very simple pivot table` is not created using vba, it is created directly in Excel.

Comment: It's best to avoid all uses of Range/Cells/etc without a qualifying worksheet object.  For example `Range("P1")` should be `ws.Range("P1")`

Comment: The error line is for setting (pc) pivot cache

Comment: Error gives:  Meathod 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: Did you update your code to qualify your Range() references with worksheet objects?  If Yes please update the code in your question to show the changes

Comment: Try `SourceData:=Range("Table2")`

Comment: My apologies, I updated the code and used your suggestions, but I am still getting an error code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, and then go Debug / Compile, you will see that the compiler does not recognize keyword `xlPivotTableVersion6`. If you provide it, the `Version` argument of `PivotCaches.Create` must be part of the `XlPivotTableVersionList` enumeration. The `Version` argument is optional and I personally never provide it.

[Option Explicit statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement)

[Declaring Variables](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DeclaringVariables.aspx)

[PivotCache.Create method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create)

[XlPivotTableVersionList enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpivottableversionlist)

Comment: That help solve the problem for that line, but unfortunately I ran into another error code when putting in the orientation for the rows/columns of the table.  I updated the code above with the error code.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on your Macro Recorder, click through the steps you need to do, and turn off your Macro Recorder.  Then, you will have all the code you need.  In addition, check out the links below.  This is a great resource for all kinds of things related to Excel, including working with Pivots.

https://www.contextures.com/pivottableindex.html

https://www.contextures.com/tiptech.html